# What does .defer() do in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I am new to rx java and I cannot understand what `Completable.defer` brings and why it's a good practice to use it.

so, what's the difference between:

```
public Completable someMethod1() {
    return Completable.defer(() -> someMethod2());
}
```

vs

```
public Completable someMethod1() {
    return someMethod2();
}
```

I can see that in the method's implementation there is some exception handling but this is surpassing me.
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Defer will makes sure each subscriber can get its own source sequence, independent of the other subscribers. Let me illustrate it with two examples:

```java
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();

Flowable<String> source =
    Flowable.just("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
    .map(v -> index.incrementAndGet() + "-" + v)
    ;

source.subscribe(System.out:println);

source.subscribe(System.out:println);
```

prints

```
1-a
2-b
3-c
4-d
5-e
6-f
7-a
8-b
9-c
10-d
11-e
12-f
```

versus

```java
Flowable<String> source =
    Flowable.defer(() -> {
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();

        return Flowable.just("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
               .map(v -> index.incrementAndGet() + "-" + v)
               ;
    })
    ;

source.subscribe(System.out:println);

source.subscribe(System.out:println);
```

prints

```
1-a
2-b
3-c
4-d
5-e
6-f
1-a
2-b
3-c
4-d
5-e
6-f
```

In the second example, there is a per subscriber state that would have been otherwise shared across all subscribers. Now since each subscriber gets its own individual sequence created, both index items as one would generally expect.

Comment: good, nice explanation, I have understood it, you have my upvote, but my question differs slightly. I have edited my question with that "vs" part.

Comment: You can make the side effects happen only when there is a subscriber. For example, in the second case, `someMethod2` does some calculation/blocking before it returns a `Completable` so you prevent the application from progressing  immediately even before there is a subscriber or RxJava involved.